# How Can I Send Remote Notification When App is Closed In React Native

Tags: react-native

I tried one signal but i didnt find schedule notification on repository guide.Only avaiable on its website.I googled a lot website and examples but nothing.I used local notification but it runs if app is running or background.

Answer (score 0):

Check 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

Create notification:
...

delivery_time_of_day
string
ALL
Use with delayed_option=timezone.

Example: "9:00AM"

basically use need to set the delivery_time_of_day in your json that you are posting with your content to 'onesignal'.